# How to create symlinks in a single directory with the lowest number of forks?

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

How to create symlinks in a single directory when:

1. The common way fails:

```bash
ln -s /readonlyShare/mydataset/*.mrc .
# -bash: /bin/ln: Argument list too long
```

2. The `find` command doesn't allow the following syntax:

```bash
find /readonlyShare/mydataset -maxdepth 1 -name '*.mrc' -exec ln -s {} . +
# find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

3. Using wild forking takes hours to complete:

```bash
find /readonlyShare/mydataset -maxdepth 1 -name '*.mrc' -exec ln -s {} . ';'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>**I was in a rush when I needed it so I didn't explore all possibilities but I worked-out something meanwhile**</sup>

Thanks to @WeihangJian answer I now know that `find ... | xargs -I {} ...` is as bad as `find ... -exec ... {} ';'`.

A correct answer to my question would be:

```bash
find /readonlyShare/mydataset -maxdepth 1 -name '*.mrc' \
    -exec sh -c 'ln -s -- "$@" .' _ {} +
```

Answer (score 2):

```sh
find readonlyShare/mydataset -name '*.mrc' -maxdepth 1 -exec ln -s '{}' '+' .
```

or if you prefer `xargs`:

```sh
find readonlyShare/mydataset -name '*.mrc' -maxdepth 1 -print0 |
  xargs -0 -P0 sh -c 'ln -s "$@" .' sh
```

If you are using BSD `xargs` instead of GNU `xargs`, it can be simpler:

```
find readonlyShare/mydataset -name '*.mrc' -maxdepth 1 -print0 |
  xargs -0 -J@ -P0 ln -s @ .
```

## Why `'{}' '+'`?

Quoted from `man find`:

```
-exec utility [argument ...] {} +
             Same as -exec, except that “{}” is replaced with as many pathnames as possible for each invocation of utility.  This behaviour is similar
             to that of xargs(1).  The primary always returns true; if at least one invocation of utility returns a non-zero exit status, find will
             return a non-zero exit status.
```

`find` is good at splitting large number of arguments:

```sh
find readonlyShare/mydataset -name '*.mrc' -maxdepth 1 -exec ruby -e 'pp ARGV.size' '{}' '+'
```

```
15925
15924
15925
15927
1835
```

## Why not `xargs -I`?

It is not efficient and slow because `-I` executes the utility per argument, for example:

```sh
printf 'foo\0bar' | xargs -0 -I@ ruby -e 'pp ARGV' @
```

```
["foo"]
["bar"]
```

```sh
printf 'foo\0bar' | xargs -0 ruby -e 'pp ARGV'
```

```
["foo", "bar"]
```

`xargs` is also good at splitting large number of arguments

```
seq 65536 | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 ruby -e 'pp ARGV.size'
```

```
5000
5000
5000
5000
5000
5000
5000
5000
5000
5000
5000
5000
5000
536
```

## Why `sh -c`?

Only BSD `xargs` have `-J` flag to put arguments in the middle of commands. For GNU `xargs`, we need the combination of `sh -c` and `"$@"` to do the same thing.

## `find -exec` vs `find | xargs`

It depends but I would suggest use `xargs` when you want to utilize all your CPUs. `xargs` can execute utility parallelly by `-P` while `find` can't.

Comment: What version of `find` are you using? I can't get `find ... -exec ln -s '{}' '+' .` to work on Linux and macOS